# formula to select a choice column

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, choice-field

I have two choice columns in a list :

choice column 1: values 1 posible 2 unlikely
choice column 2: values A bad B very bad

and I want to select another choice column based on the previous selected columns

choice or calculated column 3: values  1A 2A 1B 2B

What is the formula to calculate the third column? Can it be a choice column or should it be a calculated column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want strait concatenation use a calculated column with =[column1]&[column2]

Comment: not, is more a a function, for example:
if there are selected 1 in column 1 and A in column 2 -> 1A bad
if there are selected 2 in column 1 and A in column 2 -> 2A bad
but is not a concatenation, is more an algorithm

Comment: In that case, it would be best to build a workflow using SharePoint designer to deal with your logic.

Comment: Can you show me a link to a tutorial or similar?

Comment: To start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks Aboba, but I will need something more.

Comment: If you need more than that, I would suggest starting into some basic programming which would help you translate whats on that page into the actions and conditions you need. You may want to learn Javascript as a first language since it's used in SharePoint as well, there is a good tutorial on w3schools.com that will get you going.